# GNU Make seperate out some cpp and compile it differently

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-I
GCCCOMPFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -O -ansi -pedantic -fpic -shared -c
GCCLINKFLAGS=-shared  
DEPS = ./src/a.h ./src/b.h 
OBJ = a.o b.o 
CPPOBJ = mycpp.cpp


%.o: ./src/%.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -DTARGET_OS_LINUX $(GCCCOMPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

final: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -DTARGET_OS_LINUX $(GCCLINKFLAGS) -o ./src/$@.so $^

<newtarget>: 
            $(CC) -std=gnu++0x ..... -o mycpp.o mycpp.cpp
           How to compile mycpp.cpp with different gcc option and add it to "final" linking target
```

Now I want compile a new file "mycpp.cpp" with different GCC options and add it to the final target to link together.

```
%.o: ./src/%.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -DTARGET_OS_LINUX $(GCCCOMPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

final: $(OBJ) mycpp.o
        $(CC) -DTARGET_OS_LINUX $(GCCLINKFLAGS) -o ./src/$@.so $^

mycpp.o:
        compile ...
```

This will make mycpp getting handled by the wild card %.o

How do we separate this build targets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target-specific variables are fully explained [in the GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific), which you should consult for additional information. In the `Makefile`:

```
mycpp.o: VARIABLE=X
```

This sets a variable within the scope of a single target only. Using this you can override `CPPFLAGS`, or any other variables, when building a specific target only.

Finally, for situations where more than just a variable needs to be overridden, you can always specify an explicit rule:

```
mycpp.o: ./src/mycpp.cpp
    [ build instructions ]
```

that will override the default rule for building `.o` from `.cpp`.